# Is there a command line flag in htlatex to select options for hyperlinks?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I'm using `htlatex` to generate html files from LaTeX input. It's working fine. However, I'd like 2 versions of the html output file: one where the hyperlinks point to files on the hard drive for offline use and another version for online use (where the hyperlinks point to analogous links on the Internet).

I have over a hundred links, so it's cumbersome when making minor changes to do it with two separate raw LaTeX files. Is there a way to set a flag/switch which allows me choose which set of links individual calls to `\href` use?

Something along these lines:

```
$htlatex --someflag N filename.tex htm,0
```

where `N=1` would select the offline links and `N=2` would use the equivalent online links. If this is possible, what is the syntax? Also, how would these flag options be indicated in the raw LaTeX file?

Comment: could you please provide a minimal working example? do you specify these links by hand, using `\href` or `\url` commands, or they come from `\ref` etc?

Comment: Thanks, @michal.h21. I use hyperref package. I have calls like this: `The \href{somedirectory/report.pdf}{report} shows what I mean.` I'd this option: `The \href{https://www.report.com/report.pdf}{report} shows what I mean.` I'd like to do this without having to recode (I have over a hundred links). I would like a single input LaTeX file that allows both options/versions. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Of course I'll have edit the LaTeX file to add the online links once. But I'm hoping there's a way I can include both online and offline links in a single LaTeX file and then specify which ones I want in the html output in htlatex (or by some other method).

Answer (score 3):

`tex4ht` supports configuration file, where you can provide custom definitions for various commands. In your place, I would use a macro that holds the base path for your `\href` commands. In the configuration file, it can be redefined to point to another directory, or to completely different web page.

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\hrefroot{somedirectory/}
\begin{document}
Hello \href{\hrefroot report.pdf}{report}


\end{document}
```

Custom command `\hrefroot` is introduced. It holds the path to file and it must be used in all `\href` commands. The configuration file for `tex4ht` can look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\ifOption{external}{\renewcommand\hrefroot{https://www.report.com/}}{\renewcommand\hrefroot{report/}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important line is

```
\ifOption{external}{\renewcommand\hrefroot{https://www.report.com/}}{\renewcommand\hrefroot{report/}}
```

the rest is only required structure of the configuration file. The `\ifOption` command checks for option which can be specified on the command line. If this option is used, then the `\hrefroot` is redefined to point to external site, `report` directory is used otherwise.

Basic way to compile the document is the following:

```
make4ht -c configfilename.cfg filename.tex
```

You can specify the `external` option using the following syntax:

```
make4ht -c configfilename.cfg filename.tex "external"
```

And here is the result for both options:

```xml
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" >Hello <a 
href="report/report.pdf" >report</a>
</p>
```

and for `external`:

```xml
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" >Hello <a 
href="https://www.report.com/report.pdf" >report</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's a cool trick, but it will not solve my problem. The external files have a different directory tree structure (and sometimes different filenames). So it could be reports/report.pdf (offline) and https://www.report.com/reports/may/May15Report.pdf (online). It would be very difficult (impossible, really) for me to change that. I should have made that clear by giving a better example. Can I use something analogous to `\ifOption` within the LaTeX file? Then I could code in both versions of the link inside the LaTeX file and pick which one I want with "external" flag.

Comment: @parminides could you please edit your question and add some simple example with such markup?

Comment: No need. See my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to attention and suggestions of @michal.h21, I figured out how to do what I want.

```
\newcommand{\hrefoption}[2]{#1} % #1 = offline; #2 = online
```

Then,

```
The \href{\hrefoption{somedirectory/report.pdf}{https://www.report.com/reports/may/May15Report.pdf}}{report} shows what I mean.
```

This will use the first option and generate the offline version. If I want the online version, I change definition of `\hrefoption` to

```
\newcommand{\hrefoption}[2]{#2} % #1 = offline; #2 = online
```

so that it ignores the first argument (offline) and uses the online option.

Thank you so much for your time and attention, @michal.h21. I didn't use their suggestion per se, but they got me thinking about it the right way. Thanks.

Edit to add - It's not exactly what I requested (a flag that's set when running `htlatex`), but it does what I need with minimal effort (changing `#1` to `#2` in `\hrefoption` definition.